# 'gear postreceive' error in openshift with Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, openshift, devops

We are using redhat openshift as a solution to test and build our code.
Jenkins was running for quite some time, but now it stopped with errors...

This is the error message i'm receiving:

```
 [exec] remote: Executing Jenkins build.[K
 [exec] remote: 
 [exec] remote: You can track your build at https://jenkins-myproject.rhcloud.com/job/myjob-build[K
 [exec] remote: 
 [exec] remote: Waiting for build to schedule....................................................................................[K
 [exec] remote: **BUILD FAILED/CANCELLED**[K
 [exec] remote: Please see the Jenkins log for more details via 'rhc tail'[K
 [exec] remote: !!!!!!!![K
 [exec] remote: Deployment Halted![K
 [exec] remote: If the build failed before the deploy step, your previous[K
 [exec] remote: build is still running.  Otherwise, your application may be[K
 [exec] remote: partially deployed or inaccessible.[K
 [exec] remote: Fix the build and try again.[K
 [exec] remote: !!!!!!!![K
 [exec] remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)[K
 [exec] remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control post-receive' for /var/lib/openshift/56asdf899weersdfd5/jenkins-client[K
 [exec] remote: 
 [exec] remote: For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.[K
 [exec] To ssh://56asdf899weersdfd5@myproject-itproject.rhcloud.com/~/git/myproject.git
 [exec]    4102ab5..3291140  master -> master
```

Jenkins doens't even see a job running and the suggested 'RHC tail jenkins' shows nothing more than 'Build succeeded' (referring to a previous build)

When i try running a build from jenkins directly, everything works fine. It should run directly when we commit to our git repository directly, but this fails. Our code has been committed to git successfully, but Jenkins failed to execute.

Also, no other build is running when i push to our git repo.

Thanks for the effort trying to help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i decided to ask this question since i was searching several hours for an answer.

For some reason the builder-client was stopped: restarted & problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

you have consumed 3/3 gears !!!
check the jenkins logs : `rhc tail jenkins`